# Show password characters when logging in to Linux

Tags: linux, debian, passwords, raspberry-pi, tty

I am setting up a long-range wireless serial terminal (with a pair of XBees, if anyone is wondering) connected to my Linux box.  It's going great, but sometimes a keystroke doesn't go through.  This is usually manageable, I'll see the lack of it and hit it again.  However, it's bad when I have to try a few times to type my password because Linux doesn't show anything.  I've already added the `pwfeedback` line to my sudoers file, but I'd like the login prompt to show some feedback as well.  The Linux machine is running Debian (it's actually a raspberry pi that manages most of my home network).

Is it possible to change the tty login prompt to give feedback as I type my password?

Instead of this:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 linuxbox ttyAMA0

linuxbox login: skylarmt
Password:
```

I would like this:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 linuxbox ttyAMA0

linuxbox login: skylarmt
Password: **********
```

Comment: see this answer : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141272/27616

Comment: I don't think such a change is currently possible on config level.
Terminal login is managed by agetty which invokes /bin/login for password prompt. You could achieve described effect by changing properly login source code, recompile it and use modified version, but this requires some ANSI C knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any configuration to do this, if you REALLY want to do it you can achieve this by :
1 - modifying the getpass function in the getpass.c file in the glibc package.
2 - build libc-(VERSION).so
3 - backup the original lib/(your archcitecture)/libc.so  ( say rename to libc-(VERSION).so.bak
4 - move the new file to lib/(your archcitecture)/
5 - run ldconfig to update the cache
As an example you can replace the code that reads the password with a code that can look like this:

```
  /* Read the password. */
  // nread = __getline (&buf, &bufsize, in);

  int index=0;
  char c;
  while ( (c=getchar())!= EOF ){
     putch('*');
     buf[i]=c;
     ++i;
  }
  buf[i]='\0';
  nread=i;
```